# In Datamapper, Can I use "order by" with converted float type?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

Environment: ruby 1.9.2 / rails 3.1.1 / Datamapper 1.2.0 / MySql 5.0

I want to use this query in Datamapper 
(is there any better method?)

> select price from books order by price + 0.0
>
> (since price's type is string, expecting type conversion to float
>   through + 0.0)

and I'm using the dm-pager, I tried to this.. but It's not work..

> sort_str = DataMapper::Query::Operator.new(**:price + 0.0**, desc)
>   mbooks.page :page => page, :per_page => 10, :order => [sort_str]

Please show me the way.. ^^;

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is currently not possible. I know this doesn't answer you question but I would suggest changing this column to integer. Storing prices as strings is not a good idea.